# Incorrect size of a local array in a bash function

Tags: shell

```
foo()
{
    local arr=(-l largs\
               -m margs\
               -n nargs
              )
    echo "size of arr: ${#arr[@]}"
}
foo   # prints 1
```

The above code prints `1`, but apparently the size of `arr` should be `6`. I altered the code to:

```
foo()
{
    arr=(-l largs\
         -m margs\
         -n nargs
        )
    echo "size of arr: ${#arr[@]}"
}
foo   # prints 6
```

The latter version removes `local`, and it prints the right answer. So why? Does local matter?

PS: GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Comment: When I cut and pasted the first example, it did not paste a closing parenthesis but a unicode character (`echo '<paste>' | hexdump -C`). What editor are you using?

Comment: @glennjackman, what? I use vim, but the above code is something I wrote on the fly, not copied from some editors.

Comment: I had to fix the close-parens too (I did that when I edited the question).  The original character is U+FF09 FULL WIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS.  With 'GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)', both examples produce 6.  I'd postulate that your version of `bash` (which is even older than the version on Mac OS X) has a bug that has since been fixed.  Update your `bash`, preferably to version 4.x.